# How to loop script in a range?

Tags: python, selenium

How to make that Script2 run Script1 in a loop in a range for example 5?

Script1

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=pl&gl=PL")
time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
```

Script2

```
import YtTest

for i in range(5):
    exec("Script1")
```

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. Add a tab before `exec(...)`

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: It's possible to do `os.system('python Script1.py')`, but it would be better to have Script1 define a function that Script2 imports and calls.

Answer (score 0):

Script1.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def fetch():
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=pl&gl=PL")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    fetch()
```

Script2.py:

```
from Script1 import fetch

for i in range(5):
    fetch()
```